# nfs File Share Not Mounting

Tags: linux, nfs, debian-based

I have 2 computers
IP 192.168.2.15 - Has the files I want to share. 
I have added this line to the etc/exports file:

```
/srv/nfs4/homes   192.168.2.10(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

I also created that folder structure on 192.168.2.15

192.168.2.10 is the Client.
I try to mount with this command

```
sudo mount -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 192.168.2.15:/srv/nfs4/homes /mystuff
```

I keep getting this result:

> mount.nfs: mount point /mystuff does not exist

While on the client if I run this command:

```
showmount -e 192.168.2.15
```

This is the results I get:

> Export list for 192.168.2.15:  /srv/nfs4/homes 192.168.2.10

This at least tells me that my client can see the nfs server.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The directory where you do a mount must exist for the mount to be successful. Have you created `/mystuff` before?

Comment: Where would that be created. Would that be on 192.168.2.15 inside of /srv/nfs4/homes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serge is correct. The error message on the client is telling you exactly what the problem is. When you mount a filesystem, the mount point (directory) must exist. In this case the mount point is /mystuff. Try this:

```
sudo mkdir /mystuff
sudo mount -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 192.168.2.15:/srv/nfs4/homes /mystuff
```